# Is the number of users who visited the site during election wrong, or does "election" refer to the last phase where users vote?

Tags: bug, election, wording

Looking at the page at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1, I read the following phrase:

> 712 voters were eligible, 0 visited the site during the election, 112 visited the election page, and 0 voted

It is wrong, as there are at least two users who visited the election page, and the site: the candidate, and me.

The candidate clearly visited the election page, and also visited the site when he answered [FROM_UNIXTIME(o.created,'%d-%m-%Y') in where clause gives error](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48014/from-unixtimeo-created-d-m-y-in-where-clause-gives-error).

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

The user also visited the site before applying for the position.

I gained the Caucus badge two days ago, and I answered [Change style for the reply link in comment.tpl.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47958/change-style-for-the-reply-link-in-comment-tpl-php).

It could also be that *election* is referring to the last phase of the elections. If this would be the case, the number of users who visited the election page should be zero too, as we are still in the first phase.

Is the number of users who visited the site during election wrong, or does "election" refer to the last phase where users vote?

#### Update

*Election* excludes the nomination phase, basing on the information given in the right side, where election is said to begin on October 22 (tomorrow), while the nomination started on October 15.

[image: screenshot]

In such case, the phrase I am referring should not be shown in the nomination phase.

Comment: This is still happening: in [the AI moderator election that ended today](https://ai.stackexchange.com/election/3), "1,441 voters were eligible, 460 visited the site during the election, 469 visited the election page, and 120 voted".